# Decrease regional vCPUs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to decrease the regional quota of vCPUs in Azure. I increased the quota from 10 to 16 and now want to revert back to the original. Is there any benefit in doing so and if yes how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***As of now you can’t decrease or revert back to the regional quota usually.*** You can raise a Microsoft [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) to decrease quota

[image]